# Software to link up photos in a line to form one image

Tags: photos, jpeg

I have several (around 50) photos of multiple sections along a river, each with a metre stick in the photo for scale. I need a way to link these photos up in a single image, whilst being able to crop out the excess image to have only the metre width visible. Could anyone advise which software is best to use? 
I have 50 sets of photos for five different river reaches so the simpler and quicker the better!

Comment: Sounds interesting! You should explain what you need in more detail, best with a drawing, and example images. Do you need a picture of, say 50 picture each 1000 pixels wide, that is 50000 pixels wide? That may be hard to handle.